# Find invertible matrices P and Q

Tags: linear-algebra

Determine 3 × 3 invertible matrices $P$ and $Q$, such that $PAQ = B$, where

$A = 
\begin{pmatrix} 
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 &1 \\
0 &1 &0  
\end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 &0 \\
0 &0 &0  
\end{pmatrix}$

I wanted to use diagonalization but diagonal entries of $B$ aren't eigenvalues of $A$ or their multiples. I then thought about row operations to get from $A$ to $B$ but didn't know how. This might be simple linear algebra question but I am really stuck. Could anyone shed light on it? Many thanks.

Solved.

Comment: Row and column operations are the way to go. Are you aware of how performing row and column operations can be turned in to left/right multiplying by certain so-called ''elementary matrices''? Once you are, it's matter of computing row and column operations which will turn $A$ into $B$ (in this case: subtract row 1 from row 3, subtract column 1 from column 3, and then interchange rows 1 and 2).

Comment: right I see now, was really rusty with the definitions! Thanks a lot!